# Is there one method of adding and subtracting without a calculator?

Tags: arithmetic

One can on a sheet of paper, without a calculator, add two numbers or subtract two numbers, each with it's own method. This is second grade maths.

However, is it possible to solve both these with a third and universal method? It can be more complex, but it works no matter what.

Comment: What on earth does this have to do with simplices?

Comment: @ChrisEagle I'm not an english speaker, so I'm not very experienced with english mathematical terms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can subtract using the addition algorithm if you represent negative numbers is "10's complement".

Suppose we want to compute $5678-2780$. This is the same as $5678+(-2780)$, so if only we had a way to express $-2780$ in an addition-friendly way, we'd be set. It turns out we can do that. First extend the number we want to negate with infinitely many zeroes on the *left*:

```
...00002780
```

Then replace each of its digit $n$ by $9-n$:

```
        ...00002780
becomes ...99997219
```

Now there are infinitely many *nines* to the left. Then add 1, and keep carrying as long as there is a carry:

```
 ...9997219
+         1
------------
 ...9997220
```

The result, ${\ldots}9997220$ is the **10's complement** representation of $-2780$.

Now we can add $5678$ to ${\ldots}9997220$ using the ordinary addition algorithm:

```
        5678
+ ...9997220
------------
  ...0002898
```

And we end up with infinite 0's to the left again because the carry from 5+7 keeps propagating to kill all the 9's. Lo and behold, $5678-2780$ really is $2898$.

This is a rather silly procedure to carry out on paper in base 10, but computers calculate with negative integers in exactly this way, only in base 2.

---

Two ways to understand why this works: *First*, the initial conversion to 10's complement can be understood as subtracting 2780 from 1000...000 with a very large but finite number of zeroes. In other words, we're *adding* 1000...000 to the initial negative number, which makes it positive. Then after doing the addition, we subtract the 1000...000 simply by ignore all but "sufficiently many" last digits of the result -- we know there'll be an initial "1" out there somewhere and don't need to physically carry the one through a billion nines in order to verify it.

*Second*, it is possible to convince oneself that the strange initial manipulation of the $-2780$ actually makes the digit-for-digit subtraction algorithm into a digit-for-digit addition algorithm, if "don't carry" is taken to mean "borrow one" and "carry one" means "no borrow". In this view, the "add 1" step functions as a "artificial" carry into the ones digit position, which corresponds to the fact that there is *no* borrow from the ones position in the subtraction algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Actually, I'm asking this question because I'm making a computer method that is simply going to add, subtract, multiply and divide numbers. I need it because the language I'm writing in thinks any number greater than $9007199254740992$ is infinite. Great answer!

Comment: @FriendofKim: It is probably worth looking into whether someone has already made a bignum library for your target language. It is possible to write one oneself, but division in particular can be a tooth-puller.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I've searched the internet, but I haven't found anything that isn't compiled, obfuscated and embedded in much other code so I can't extract it. + It is copyrighted..

Comment: This method is just fantastically smart and yet not logically difficult, at least not how you explained it!

Comment: Hmm... I've been calculating on a paper for a while now. As I see it, one can make a few rules. If you always do A-B. Given A-B where |A|>|B|. One can calculate with as many digits as the number with the most digits, and then neglect all the 1's in the answer to get the right answer.

Comment: It probably is correct. I'm going to test my algorithms with a recursive fibonacci generator, so if the numbers are correct, the algorithms are probably correct as well.

Comment: @FriendofKim: To be sure, I'd compute the result with more _more_ digit than the largest of the operand, and then possibly ignore upper digits afterwards if they turn out to equal the infinitely repeated sign digit. For example $80-(-70)$ is $160$, but that is one digit longer than any of the incoming operands ($-70$ is ...999930 with two significant digits).

Comment: Yes, but $80-(-70)$ would by my algorithm be interpreted as $80+70$ since, as I see it, this method cannot be applied without running a else/elseif for these four conditions: +A+B, +A-B (|A|>|B|?), -A+B, -A-B.

Answer (score 2):

Subtracting $b$ from $a$ is nothing more than adding $-b$ to $a$:

$a - b = a + -b$. In this case, $-b$ is the additive inverse of $b$.

So addition covers both addition and subtraction. In whatever context, you can think of substraction of a number as the addition of its additive inverse (e.g., computes use only addition, where "negative" numbers are in two's complement form, etc.)

Similarly, dividing $a$ by $b$ is nothing more than multiplying $a$ and $\dfrac1b$, since $\dfrac1b$ is the multiplicative inverse of $b$:

$\dfrac ab = a\cdot \dfrac 1b$

So multiplication covers both multiplication and division.

Comment: On the other hand, the usual way to add a negative number is to subtract _its_ inverse... so it is not clear that this gets us anywhere.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Exactly! I've already thought about this solution, but it again brings us back to start as you Henning stated.

Comment: I agree with you on the multiplication/division, but not on the addition/subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

$\rm {\bf Hint}\ \  note\rm\,\ 43-21\, =\, 43+79\!-\!100\, =\, 43+79,\:$ dropping final carry. Expressed modularly

$\rm\ mod\,\ 100\!:\ 43-21 \,\equiv\, 43+79\, \equiv\, 22$